# how do I look for the same shape that has the identical fields?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap

I am trying too look at a set of shapes in ArcMap and see if they are the same shape and same asset name. I can have the same shape but different assets. I wrote this using arcpy and a cursor:

```
AssetName = srow.getValue("AssetName")
shape = srow.getValue("Shape")
field = shape.area
ID = srow.getValue("OBJECTID")
if field in areaList:
    if ID in ShapeArea.keys():
        ShapeArea[ID].append("Duplicate Shapes")
    else:
        ShapeArea[ID] = ["Duplicate Shapes"]
else:
    areaList.append(field)
```

How do I use this too compare the shapes it found to look and see if the asset name is the same?

Comment: What release of ArcGIS are you working with? Are the features in the same or different feature classes?

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.2.2

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ShapeArea is a dictionary you built somewhere...

```
#if ID exists, check shape
if ID in ShapeArea.keys():
    #If shape is not in shape list, add it
    if not shape in ShapeArea[ID]:
        ShapeArea[ID].append("Duplicate Shapes")
#if ID does not exist, add ID and shape to dict.
else ShapeArea[ID] = shape
```

If you have a feature from a cursor and want to check if it exists somewhere else, you could query the table with a where clause containing the Id and shape from the feature. If no rows are returned then it is unique.

```
exists = arcpy.MakeTableView_management('INPUT TABLE',"exists", "AssetName = '{}' and Shape = '{}'".format(AssetName,shape))
if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(exists)[0])==0
    Do Stuff
```

There is an interesting discussion on the relative performance of table views vs cursors here https://geonet.esri.com/thread/12041

Final thought:  Do you need to use a cursor? There is a built in GP tool called "Find Identical" that already has this functionality. 
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000054000000

Comment: Sorry about that. I do use a cursor for this operation and I did indeed create dictionary called ShapeArea. I forgot to include those two items in the snip it of the code I put here.

Comment: So were you able to get the comparison to work with the dictionary? You must have read all the shapes and IDs into the dictionary first, so have you tried the table view or search cursor to see if they are faster?

Comment: Yes I was. I found a way to look at the shapes by there object ID but I was wondering if there was a way to use the object ID and the assetname fields